# Yii2 run only specific migration

Tags: mysql, yii, yii2, database-migration

In Yii2, when I use the

> yii migrate

command, I get a long list of remaining migrations. How can I only run one specific migration in the list without performing the others?

Comment: First, your migration should be synced. But, in some cases if you don't want to update others; simply move those migration files from your migration folder to another directory. And hit `yii migrate` in console. (ie. keep only that specific file in migration folder)

Comment: you need to run **up to the given** migrations means that all the migrations in between the specified migration and the migration last applied, will also run. you can use `./yii migrate/to m150101_185401_create_some_table` command for that

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Run `migrate/history` to list migrations have been applied:

```
./yii migrate/history
```

Copy the name of migration you want to return to later (lets say it is 'm160101_185401_initial_migration'). Save it somewhere because you're going to need this later.

Mark migration history **at the one just before the one you need to run**:

```
./yii migrate/mark m170101_185401_create_news_table
```

Run one migration:

```
./yii migrate 1
```

Reset migration history:

```
./yii migrate/mark m160101_185401_initial_migration
```

Answer (score 2):

```
yii migrate --migrationPath=@app/modules/forum/
```

Comment: Thank you a lot.
Especially, I should admit (for others), it requires you to create some temporary folder, copy migration file in it and rename this file. But, anyway, it solves a problem)

Answer (score 1):

To run specific migration, you can mark(skip) migrations upto just before one you want run.
You can mark migration by using one of following command:

1. Using timestamp to specify the migration `yii migrate/mark 150101_185401`
2. Using a string that can be parsed by strtotime() `yii migrate/mark "2015-01-01 18:54:01"`
3. Using full name`yii migrate/mark m150101_185401_create_news_table`
4. Using UNIX timestamp `yii migrate/mark 1392853618`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip some migrations that have been implemented in your database without running the migrations, you set your migrations state without running them.

By "marking" the migrations you also assure they will no longer be re-prompted and will be regarded as "done".

you can read about marking in the Yii docs [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations#modifying-migration-history)